# Media directory in production not working

Tags: python, django, django-media

The media directory is working as expected in my local machine but when I push the code to Heruko or Cloud Foundry the media is not working.

How to rectify this issue?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

            url(r'^profile/$', view_profile, name='view_profile'),

          ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
# Medta files location
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What's wrong? Are you getting 404? What's your production configuration. Paste your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` too.

Comment: @Arman Ordookhani  - yes I am getting 404 error when I try to check the uploaded profile pic in production (Heruko and cloud foundary).but it's working in my local machine

Comment: Are you running project with `DEBUG=True`? Heroku can't be configured to serve media/static files. You should serve them within Python.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani - Yes i am running just to see the error.. i am clue how to handle within python ?

Comment: Don't know whats happening. Try printing list of files in `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. It may help to see weather the actual file exists or not.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani its working in Debug mode ..but not working if debug if False any idea y

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani -- the media file is not in my local machine if the Debug is False